# Sign of arc length

Tags: calculus

I'm a bit confused about the sign of the infinitesimal arc length

$ ds = \sqrt {(\frac {dx}{dt})^2+ (\frac {dy}{dt})^2 } dt$

I've read that in the derivation of the above from 
$ ds = \sqrt {1+ (\frac {dy}{dx})^2 } dx$
 the assumption made is that $\frac {dx}{dt} > 0$ over the interval of $ t $ which we are concerned with, but I've also seen other sources make absolutely no mention of this, and use the first equation whatever the sign of of  $\frac {dx}{dt} $ over the interval we are concerned with.

So naturally I'm a bit confused about how I should approach the sign of $ ds $. For example, I am trying to compute the line integral

$\displaystyle\int_C (x^2-xy) ds $, from (0,4) to (4,0), C given by $ x^2+y^2=16$, using the parametric equations $ x=4\cos t$ and $ y=4\sin t $, and so far the sign of my answer is different from the one at the back of the book. And it occurs to me that in fact $\frac {dx}{dt} < 0$ over the interval I'm concerned with, so is that the root of the problem?  If so, why don't I see the assumption mentioned in many sources?

EDIT: Evidently I need to put my problem across much more directly.  Using two different methods to solve the question results in a sign discrepancy which I find I can only explain away by considering that $\frac {dx}{dt} < 0$

M1) $ y=\sqrt {16-x^2} $ (y is positive in the quadrant we are concerned with)

$ \frac {dy}{dx}= \frac {-x}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}$

$ ds = \sqrt {1+ (\frac {dy}{dx})^2 } dx = \sqrt {\frac {16}{16-x^2} }dx $

Using the parametrization $ x=4\cos t$ and $ y=4\sin t $, we have 
$ dx=-4\sin t dt $, hence
$ ds = \sqrt {\frac {16}{16-x^2} }dx = \frac {4}{4\sin t} (-4\sin t dt) = -4dt$

M2) Using the same parametrization and the formula
$ ds = \sqrt {(\frac {dx}{dt})^2+ (\frac {dy}{dt})^2 } dt$
We have
$ ds = \sqrt {(\frac {dx}{dt})^2+ (\frac {dy}{dt})^2 } dt = 4dt$

Okay, so why are the signs different? Note: the limits don't correct for the sign since the parametrization is the same in both cases; you'd integrate from $\pi/2$ to $0$ either way.

What SPECIFICALLY am I doing wrong??

Also see the derivation for infinitesimal arc length given here : http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArcLength.aspx

Comment: Why should the sign of $\frac {dx}{dt}$ matter? You'll still have $(\frac {dx}{dt})^2 > 0$ regardless.

Comment: Because if you factor $ \frac {dx}{dt}$ out from $ ds =\sqrt {1+(\frac {dy}{dx})^2} $ it'll have absolute value bars around it

Comment: Again, why should the sign of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ matter? You'll still have $|\frac{dx}{dt}|$ regardless.

Comment: $\frac {1}{|\frac {dx}{dt}|} \sqrt {(\frac {dx}{dt})^2 + (\frac {dy}{dt})^2} \frac {dx}{dt} dt $ we can only cancel out he absolute value bars if we assume that $ \frac {dx}{dt} > 0$

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to understand where you're coming from. A more careful derivation would show that there is a compensating sign change in $dt$ that takes care of your problem. I suspect your teacher didn't do a very good job teaching this material.

Answer (score 1):

In front of $ \sqrt { }  $  sign we have a $\pm$ whether explicitly written or not. By *convention* distance is taken positive.If we are particular about sign of distance we take is as separation between ordered pair of points.

The ambiguity is inevitable because distances are defined from Pythagorean relation  using squares of distances. The ambiguity extends to areas and volumes also.

Comment: Narasimham: "_In front of √ sign we have a ± whether explicitly written or not._" -- Correct. "_By convention distance is taken positive._" -- True as well. "_If we are particular about sign of distance [... then ...]_" -- If we are particular about distinguishing the two cases $$ds=\left| \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2} \right| ~dt$$ from $$ds= -\left|\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}\right|~ dt $$ then we can still insist on $$ds > 0$$ matched with either $$dt = |dt| > 0,$$ or in the other case: $$dt = -|dt| < 0.$$

Comment: $t$ is also signed.

Comment: Narasimham: "$t$ _is also signed._" -- Sure. But does this have anything to do with the sign of $\frac{ds}{dt}$ ??

Comment: If $x,y $ are signed, $  \frac {dy}{dx}$ can have any sign.

Comment: Narasimham: "_If_ $x, y$ _are signed,_ $\frac{dy}{dx}$ _can have any sign._" -- $\frac{dy}{dx}$ can have any sign regardless of whether or not $x, y$ are signed. For instance: $\frac{dy}{dx}$ can have any sign for suitable arcs which are entirely "[in coordinate quadrant I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrant_(plane_geometry))". But again: Does this have anything to do with the sign of $\frac{ds}{dt}$ ??, which is the main point of the OP question, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

The only assumption I am aware of is that $C$ should be a smooth curve. Also, it is to be noted that the value of the line integral does not depend on the parametrisation of the curve, if the curve is traversed only once as $t$ goes from say $a$ to $b$. Of course $f$ should be a continuous function.

In $ \displaystyle\int_C (x^2-xy) ds $ we choose the parametrisation to be $x= cos(t)$ and $y=sin(t)$   ,  $ 0 \leq t \leq \pi /2$ and then take the negative (As we are going from $(4,0)$ to $(0,4)$ ). The curve is smooth and it gets traversed only once as move from $0$ to $\pi /2 $

Comment: Hmm yes I did do that ($64\int_{\pi /2}^0 \cos^2 t - \sin t\cos t dt $) and I got the wrong sign. Also I've found that using a different parametrization ($ y = 4\cos t, x =4\sin t$, going from 0 to $\pi /3$) and the sign turned out correct!  Would someone kindly point out where I went wrong

Comment: @user 1415 554 In front of $ \sqrt { }  $  sign we have a $\pm$ whether explicitly written or not. By *convention*, distance is taken positive.If we are particular about sign of distance we take is as separation between ordered pair of points.

The ambiguity is inevitable because distances are defined from Pythagorean relation  using squares of distances. The ambiguity extends to areas and volumes also.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a bit confused about the sign of the infinitesimal arc length [...]

Customarily, an ["*arc*" is a closed segment of a differentiable curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry)) while a ["*curve*" is a smooth map from an interval (a non-empty closed connected subset) of the real numbers into a smooth manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Topology);

$\gamma : [a, z] \rightarrow \mathcal M$ constitutes a curve where

- there is a subset $\mathcal C \subseteq \mathcal M$ such that $\gamma : [a, z] \longleftrightarrow \mathcal C$, which is called the image of curve $\gamma$ and which constitutes *the arc*,
- any smooth (or at least continuous) function $\gamma : [a, z] \longleftrightarrow \mathcal C$ thereby constitutes a (real-valued) parametrization of arc $\mathcal C$,
- by the convention of [how to denote closed intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Including_or_excluding_endpoints): $a < z$,

  - $\gamma[~a~]$ is (or: maps to) one "end" of arc $\mathcal C$, and $\gamma[~b~]$ is (or: maps to) "the other end" of arc $\mathcal C$, and generally these are two distinct elements of set $\mathcal M$. (At least that's assumed in the following argument. The other possible case, namely that both "ends" are actually the same element of set $\mathcal M$, presents a complication which however leads to the same conclusions.)

For a particular arc "$\widehat{JQ}$" with concrete distinct ends $J$ and $Q \in \mathcal M$ two classes of parametrizations can be distinguished:

- either those with $\gamma[~a~] \mapsto J$ and $\gamma[~z~] \mapsto Q$,
- or just as well those with $\gamma[~a~] \mapsto Q$ and $\gamma[~z~] \mapsto J$.
  (Simply using the symbol "$\gamma$" in expressing both cases might be considered an abuse of notation, btw., so I welcome suggestions for improvement.
  Also, note that "$\widehat{QJ}$" would be denoting the exact same subset of $\mathcal M$ as "$\widehat{JQ}$"; and hence the very same arc. Other conventions of terminology might require a somewhat different line of argument.)

Now, to arc $\widehat{JQ}$ there is assigened a particular value of arc length $\ell_{\widehat{JQ}} > 0$; and likewise a particular (smaller, positive) value of arc length to each segment of arc $\widehat{JQ}$.

Among the many parametrizations of arc $\widehat{JQ}$ are obviously several of the form $\lambda : [0, \ell_{\widehat{JQ}}] \longleftrightarrow \widehat{JQ}$,
and among them are in turn the **arc length parametrizations of arc** $\widehat{JQ}$:

$$s : [0, \ell_{\widehat{JQ}}] \longleftrightarrow \widehat{JQ}$$

such that

$$ \forall K, P ~|~ \widehat{KP} \subseteq \widehat{JQ} : s^{-1}[~P~] > s^{-1}[~K~] \implies s^{-1}[~P~] - s^{-1}[~K~] = \ell_{\widehat{KP}}$$.

Corresponding to the two classes of parametrizations discussed above, there are in fact
**two distinct ("opposite") possible arc length parametrizations** of the given arc $\widehat{JQ}$, namely:

- either with $s[~0~] \mapsto J$ and $s[~\ell_{\widehat{JQ}}~] \mapsto Q$,
- or just as well with $s[~0~] \mapsto Q$ and $s[~\ell_{\widehat{JQ}}~] \mapsto J$.
  (Again, it doesn't seem the best notation to denote both of these two distinct arc length parametrizations by the same symbol "$s$". As far as this nevertheless is the convention it certainly contributes to the confusion alluded to in the question.)

Consequently, if a particular parametrization $t : [a, z] \longleftrightarrow \widehat{JQ}$ satisfies (throughout) "$\frac{ds}{dt} > 0$" with respect to one particular of the two described arc length parametrizations $s$
then necessarily holds "$\frac{ds}{dt} < 0$" with respect to the other.

This argument doesn't change after the introduction of particular coordinate values ($x, y, ...$) for elements of set $\mathcal M$, of course.

> Okay, so why are the signs different?

Due to the given the parametrization holds $\frac{dx}{dt} \le 0$ in the range of parameter $t$. Consequently the two formulas

> M1) [...] $ds = \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 }~dx$

and

> M2) [...] $ds = \sqrt{ \left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{dy}{dt} \right)^2 }~dt$

are referring to the two "opposite" arc length parametrizations; even though they are both denoted by the same symbol "$s$".

> What SPECIFICALLY am I doing wrong??

Nothing except for using arguably confusing notation; namely denoting both distinct "opposite" arc length parametrizations by the same symbol "$s$".
(But, obviously, my answer suffers from this shortcoming itself; at least until further notice.)

However, along with requiring of parametrizations $t$ that "$\exists \frac{dx}{dt}, \exists \frac{dy}{dt}, ...$" it may be conventional to require "$\frac{dx}{ds} > 0$" and/or "$\frac{dx}{dt} > 0$", and thereby "$\frac{ds}{dt} > 0$".

If you were supposed to obey these conventions then the parametrization you've been using is wrong; you might have used instead:

$x = 4~\text{Sin}[~\theta~], \qquad y = 4~\text{Cos}[~\theta~]$.